# Not able to uninstall Java 17. Getting error related to dependency

Tags: apt, 20.04, java, software-uninstall

I am new to ubuntu and using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. I had installed Java 17 recently but now I want to uninstall it but getting following dependency error. Please help me out:

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${binary:Package}\n' | grep -E -e '^(ia32-)?(sun|oracle)-java' -e '^openjdk-' -e '^icedtea' -e '^(default|gcj)-j(re|dk)' -e '^gcj-(.*)-j(re|dk)' -e '^java-common' | xargs sudo apt-get -y remove
[sudo] password for saurabh: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 jdk-17 : Depends: libc6-i386 but it is not installed
          Depends: libc6-x32 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Have you followed the suggestion to try `sudo apt --fix-broken install`? 

Comment: Thanks. It worked today. Yesterday I tried but it was throwing this above error. Maybe I might have tried again in the new terminal.